How to disable accidental trackpad input on Apple Silicon hardware running macOS Sonoma?
I know we have an old thread on the Apple SE site about this, but none of the posted solutions work on the newer Apple Silicon (M1/M2/M3) Macs running macOS Sonoma.
I have tested Karabiner-Multitouch-Extension but sadly it does not work yet.
This is a life saver for me because I have multiple sclerosis disease and need to be able to use an external keyboard and external apple trackpad in the middle. (No mouse is possible to use).


What options exist for the current hardware and OS for this accessibility issue?

Welcome to Ask Different. There is a little overlap for the sites Stack Overflow, Super User and Ask Different, but you chose the best site for Apple hardware specific questions. I’ll touch up the post to remove some meta so it reads just like the [tour] explains on scope and format.

Thank you for your friendly welcome!
